# Nifi-1.0 keeps crashing

Tags: apache-nifi

I've installed NiFi 1.0 and imported a template.
I'm processing some files and after awhile NiFi crashes.

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
2018-10-09 18:10:07,416 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr [Error] :10768:38: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'template'. One of '{processGroup, remoteProcessGroup, connection, controllerService}' is expected.
```

Comment: The template that was exported. Was it exported from a < 1.0 version NiFi instance or a > 1.0 NiFi instance?

Comment: Please share the template content so we can diagnose the issue. Also, please note that Apache NiFi 1.0 was released over 2 years ago. There are much more recent versions available (1.7.1 is the current stable release).

Comment: I also have some custom processors which do not work on a newer version.

Comment: Here's the link to the template: 
http://www.rapidshare.com.cn/7ndpcga

Comment: Voted to close as not reproducible (nifi 1.0 is so old that it is unlikely this can be reproduced on modern versions of Nifi)